# How do I solve this rotational inertia problem?

Tags: integration, rotations

My friend has asked me to look over a physics homework problem.
[image]

I've attempted this multiple times, and I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong.
My idea was that I have to use the parallel axis theorem in order to relate two integrals and solve for the value of B.

I know the integral from the left end is the following:

$$
\int _0 ^L {x^2 B (L^2 - x^2)} dx = \frac {2BL^5} {15}
$$

And I believe the integral from the middle would be the following:

$$
2 \int _{L/2} ^L {(\frac L 2 - x)^2 B (L^2 - x^2)} dx = \frac {3BL^5} {160}
$$

So the parallel axis theorem should be able to relate these two in the following way:

$$
\frac {2BL^5} {15} = \frac {3BL^5} {160} + M(\frac L 2)^2
$$

Which gives a B value of  $\frac {24M} {11L^3}$  which can be substituted into the left integral:

$$
\frac {2(\frac {24M} {11L^3})L^5} {15} = \frac {16ML^2} {55}
$$

Unfortunately, this is not an answer choice to the problem, and I've tried it many times. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and any pointers would be much appreciated, thank y'all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to do the integral from the middle or use the parallel axis theorem.
Your first integral is the answer, since $x$ is the distance to the $Y$-axis and you are correctly computing $\int x^2dM$. All you need is to relate $B$ to $M$. You know that the total mass is $M$, that is
$$
\int_0^LB(L^2-x^2)\,dx=M,
$$
which gives
$$
B=\frac{3M}{2L^3}.
$$
Plugging in this value into your first formula, you get
$$
I=\frac{ML^2}{5}.
$$

Comment: I feel like such a fool, can't believe I didn't think of fully integrating dM/dx